# System.Collections.Generic.List from CS to Js variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

on MyPage.aspx.cs I have List of object

```
     protected List<MyObj> myObjList =null;
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    myObjList = GetObjByUserId("23423");
    }
```

on aspx page I want to assign this list of objects to JS variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
var BookingsList = <%=myObjList %>;

</script>
```

but is assign type like string=>

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[myObj]
```

how I can to assign my collection of object from CS to JS variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using JavaScriptSerializer like following:

c# Code

```
Student student = new Student();
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string StudentJson = oSerializer.Serialize(resources);
```

and in your aspx code get it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonStudent = <%=StudentJson%>;            
</script>
```

Please make sure that StudentJson is a public or protected property in your backend class

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the list in javascript format. In pure javascript you are looking for the following output (as an example):

```
var jsList = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
```

To get this from .NET you need to use the `Join` function to combine list items into the appropriate format. The complete line of code looks like:

```
var jsList = <%= "['" + string.Join("', '", myObjList.ToArray()) + "']" %>;
```

Note that this assumes your "ToString" on your elements generates the output you are looking for and does not include single quotes. Hope that helps!

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Join' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Alex Sorry - haven't opened the compiler yet. Try the updated code.

Comment: @drew_w I guess it should be var jsList = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];

Comment: Error   8   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join(string, params object[])' and 'string.Join<MyObj>(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyObj>)'

Comment: @Alex remove the `.ToArray` so it will use the generic override.

Comment: @Alex This latest code compiles and runs for me in a test application. If you have a type error on compile you may need to explicitly cast the value so the compiler knows which version of the `Join` method you are calling. Otherwise this should work. Best of luck!

Comment: @DatRid Noted & fixed. Thanks!