# List of Objects To Json String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

***How do you turn a list of Objects into a JSON String?***

The code below returns only one attribute, People. How to add multiple attributes to it? I have been using JsonConvert to change an object into JSON format. I would be open other options / opinions on how to do it. Any help would be much appriciated!

**Wanted Response:**

```
{"People":
    {"Person": 
        {"FirstName":"Mike", "LastName":"Smith", "Age":"26"}
    },
    {"Person": 
        {"FirstName":"Josh", "LastName":"Doe", "Age":"46"}
    },
    {"Person": 
        {"FirstName":"Adam", "LastName":"Fields", "Age":"36"}
    }
}
```

**The Person Class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get ;set; }
    public string LastName { get ;set; }
    public int Age { get ;set; }    
}
```

**Processing Logic**

```
public JsonResult GetAllPeople()
{
    List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>(); 
    String responseJSON = "";

    foreach(string data in something){

        //Some code to get data
        Person p = new Person(); 
        p.FirstName = data.FirstName ;
        p.LastName  = data.LastName 
        p.Age = data.Age;

        responseJSON += new { Person = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p) };
    }

    return Json(new { People = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseJSON ) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: The exact string you've posted as your "wanted output" is not valid JSON.  It has a property identifier followed by three bare objects.

Comment: Check this, It may works for you too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547890/system-collections-generic-list-from-cs-to-js-variable/26549074#26549074

Comment: A better approach would be to use WebAPI, then you simply return the `List<Person>` and the framework handles converting it to Json (or Xml) according to the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list of objects.

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>(); 
persons.Add(new Person { FirstName  = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
// etc
return Json(persons, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

will return

```
[{"FirstName":"John", "LastName":"Doe"}, {....}, {....}]
```

Comment: this won't create an object with a People array, which is the desired result.  Pop it into an anonymous object before serializing.

Comment: @iceburg, Not sure exactly what OP wants. Title says _List of objects_ and _Wanted Response_ is not valid

Comment: @iceburg You're correct but this works fine. It will just use indexs rather than a "People" array attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
return Json()
```

will actually serialize the object it takes as a parameter.  As you are passing in a json string, it's getting double encoded.
Create an anonymous object with a property named People, then serialize it.
so you can:

```
return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {People=PersonList}))
```

or

```
return Json(new {People=PersonList});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add a class, we will name it `People`

```
public class People{
    public Person Person{set;get;}
}

public JsonResult GetAllPeople()
{
    List<People> PeopleList= new List<People>();
    foreach(string data in something){
    //Some code to get data
    Person p = new Person(); 
    p.FirstName = data.FirstName ;
    p.LastName  = data.LastName 
    p.Age = data.Age;

    PeopleList.Add(new People(){Person = p});
    }        
    return Json(new { People = PeopleList },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

this shall return exactly what you want